# É possível ponteiro de ponteiro acessar membro de classes?

Tags: c++

Estou iniciando um aplicativo Gtkmm com Glade. Quero colocar todas as funções manipuladora de eventos em uma classe separada da qual o arquivo glade está sendo instanciado.
Seguindo o exemplo do livro Programando com gtkmm 3 na seção Glade e Gtk::Builder, consigo exibir a janela tranquilamente. O problema acontece quando tento acessar um membro da classe que utiliza o glade, na classe manipuladora de eventos.

Seguem as classes:

gtimer-gui.h

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

gtimer-gui.cpp

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

main.cpp

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

gtimer-controller.h

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

gtimer-controller.cpp

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao tentar acessar acessar o botão p_new para vincular o manipulador de eventos recebo a seguinte mensagem:

request for member 'p_new' in '*gtimergui'  which is of pointer type 'Gtimergui*' (maybe you meant to use ' -> '  ?)

O que pode estar ocorrendo de errado se já estou utilizando o símbolo correto para manipular membros de um ponteiro?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver a situação com um feedback no site do gcc.gnu.org. Parece que foi um bug do compilador que emitou uma mensagem errada: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91138

De:
gtimergui->p_new->signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(this, &GtimerController::Temporized));

Troquei para:
(*gtimergui)->p_new->signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(this, &GtimerController::Temporized));